# NTFS hard disk now recognized as 'RAW'

Tags: windows-xp, ntfs, formatting

My Windows XP was recently corrupted and my hard disk was password protected. In an effort to retrieve my old info I slaved my hard disk to a friends PC.

I changed the permissions on my old, slaved drive and all was well. I then installed a secondary 250 GB slave so I could backup the data on his 'D:' (primary slave) drive, which he promised to me after I was done.

Then, when I uninstalled my old drive, his primary slave was no longer present in 'My Computer'. I removed the new 250 GB drive, but his primary slave was still not visible.

I did a little research and found that I could reassign the drive letter to make it visible via the disk manager and reassigned the 'D:' designation. The drive is now visible, but it says that the disk is unformatted, which is obviously not true.

How can I rectify this without formatting the drive?

Comment: Most probably you have to try recover it through `TestDisk` and download [Swissknife](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=swissknife+download&sugexp=chrome,mod=2&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) to format the raw drive.

Answer (score 2):

Try to recover the volume with [`TestDisk`](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk).

Comment: TestDisk only allows to get the data, there's no mean to turn it back into NTFS without losing data. If there is ? please let me know.

Comment: A lost volume can be recovered in-place. Lost files, however, should be recovered to some other volume to avoid inadvertent overwriting of other lost files on the same volume.

Comment: please let me know how to recover a lost volume in place. I've   recovered all files from that.

Comment: This is covered by the [documentation](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step).